# Json schema ,check double quotes start and end of the string

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json property **Employee-name** which contains a string with double quotes at the start and end like this:

`"ramesh yadav"`

I have a schema.json file to validate schema of my json data.

I wanna know how I can write regular expression inside schema file so it will check for double quotes

```
"Employee-name": {
  "type":"string",
  "pattern":??????
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You use the line start (`^`) and end (`$`) regex operands together with escaped (via `\`) double quotes to make the regex a valid JSON string. All put together, the following should work:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Employee-name":{
      "type":"string",
      "pattern": "^\".*\"$"
    }
  }
}
```